# Select for every row between two columns based on condition in another column in R

Tags: r

may someone help me to find the answer thread or provide a method for solution? I can not find a solution.

*What I want to do:*

For every row if the value in column "x" is "A" then select the value in column "y" from the same row and if the value in column "x" is "B" then select the value in column "z" from the same row.
Ideally collected in a vector to include as a new column in the df afterwards.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "B", "A"), y = c(1,2,3,4), z = c(4,3,2,1), fix.empty.names = FALSE)
df

  x y z
1 A 1 4
2 B 2 3
3 B 3 2
4 A 4 1

result 

[1] 1 3 2 4
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume `x` is always "A" or "B":

```
ifelse(df$x == "A", df$y, df$z)
```

More generally:

```
ifelse(df$x == "A", df$y, ifelse(df$x == "B", df$z, NA))
```

You can, of course, assign this directly as a new column: `df$result <- ifelse...`

If you like `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    result = case_when(
      x == "A" ~ y,
      x == "B" ~ z,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    )
  )
```

Comment: you are amazing thank you very much. This was what I was looking for!